Target class [admin] does not exist error
This error shows when I log in with the admin profile. I declared the admin at but still giving me the error.
Kernel.php:
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    ];

and this is how web.php route looks like:
Route::middleware(['web', 'auth', 'admin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/admin', [AdminDashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');


I tried to use some AI tools but no results. Please help me with this

The error is not that the auth is not working, you do have an admin set somewhere, share the full stacktrace error please...

Its not the issue of Route or middleware .Please share entire error-block.
